# NODEjs synchronizing exec statements inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, exec, fs

I want to create a program where in I read the files from inside a directory and then grep those names in other directories.

Here is the code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var internalCount = 0;
var i = -1;
for (; i < fileNamesInDir.length / 2;) {
  if (i === internalCount) {
    continue;
  }
  (function () {
    i = internalCount;
    var j = i;
    exec('grep -nre js/' + fileNamesInDir[j] +
      ' ./ --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=searchResults.txt',
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        outputString += "\n";
        outputString +=
          "***********************************************************";
        outputString += "\n";
        outputString += "RESULTS FOR  ::" + fileNamesInDir[j];
        outputString += "\n";
        outputString +=
          "***********************************************************";
        outputString += "\n";
        outputString += stdout;
        outputString += "\n";
        if (++internalCount === fileNamesInDir.length) {
          writeToFile();
        }
      });
  })();
}
```

The issue is that the execute statements are not synchronous and the callback functions return data asynchronously. To resolve this, I have taken another variable and continue the for loop if iterating index is same as that var. However, with this code, it goes into infinite loop with no exec statements firing.

Comment: Where are you incrementing `i`?

Comment: yes .. once the callback function executes..internalcount is increamented. So for the next iteration i is not equal to internalCount and then the continue would not happen and the self executing function would run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `for` loop in Javascript runs synchronously and here is no way to tell it to wait for anything in the loop.  If you try various hacks, you just end up running into roadblocks or infinite loops because of Javascript's single threaded nature.  So ... basically you can't make a `for` loop wait for an async operation inside the loop to finish before going to the next iteration of the loop.  So, you have to solve your issue a different way.

---

Here's a common scheme for iterating asynchronously where operations are coordinated and done one after the other:

```
var i = 0;
var outputString = "";
function next() {
    if (i < fileNamesInDir.length) {
        exec('grep -nre js/' + fileNamesInDir[i] +
          ' ./ --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=searchResults.txt',
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString +=
              "***********************************************************";
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString += "RESULTS FOR  ::" + fileNamesInDir[i];
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString +=
              "***********************************************************";
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString += stdout;
            outputString += "\n";
            i++;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        writeToFile();
    }
}
next();
```

This will run each of the grep operations serially so that the results are concatenated in order.

---

But, you don't have to run this type of code serially.  You can run all these operations in parallel as long as you collect the results in order like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var results = [];
var doneCntr = 0;
fileNamesInDir.forEach(function(item, index) {
        exec('grep -nre js/' + item +
          ' ./ --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=searchResults.txt',
          function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            var outputString = "";
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString +=
              "***********************************************************";
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString += "RESULTS FOR  ::" + item;
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString +=
              "***********************************************************";
            outputString += "\n";
            outputString += stdout;
            outputString += "\n";
            results[index] = outputString;
            ++doneCntr;
            if (doneCntr === fileNamesInDir.length) {
                writeToFile(results.join(""));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Your code is also missing error handling which needs to be added.

---

My favorite way to do this is with promises and let `Promise.all()` do the work of collecting results in order for us:

```
function execP(cmd) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({stdout, stderr});
            }
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(fileNamesInDir.map(function(item) {
    return execP('grep -nre js/' + item +
          ' ./ --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=searchResults.txt').then(function(data) {
        return "\n" +
           "***********************************************************\n" + 
           "RESULTS FOR  ::" + item + "\n" + 
           "***********************************************************\n" +
           data.stdout + "\n";

    });
})).then(function(results) {
    var output = results.join("");
    // process output here
}, function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Comment: If `execSync` is used inside `for` loop it works. Means suppose 3 iterations of `for` loop, so it waits inside loop for each iteration's `execSync`.

Comment: @Yusuf - Yes, you can use blocking `execSync()` if that is appropriate for your program.  No server should ever use blocking I/O because it would ruin the scalability of your server.  Now in 2021, you can also get a `for` loop to wait for `await` if you're awaiting a `promise`.